# A motorcycle license plate consists of two or three letters followed by four digits. How many license plates can be made?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I believe this question involves the rule of sum and the fundamental counting principle. I think my logic here is wrong, but I hope you could correct it.

(26 P 2 + 26 P 3)(10 P 4)
= 8.19*10^7

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format math on this site. To begin with, enclose all math expressions (including numbers) in `$` signs. For example, `$x_1^2$` will give you $x_1^2$. You'll get a much better response if your posts are easy to read.

Comment: The letters can be the same, and so can the digits.

Comment: @saulspatz, thank you for letting me know! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the letters and digits *cannot* be repeated, then your answer is correct.

If they *can*, then you have 26 options every time you select a letter, and 10 options every time you select a digit, so it would be $(26^2+26^3)\cdot 10^4$